# How to rigorously evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } n \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}1- \sqrt[n]{\sin(t)}dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> How to rigorously   evaluate $L:=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } n \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}1- \sqrt[n]{\sin(t)}dt$?

I tried to use the beat function since $$B(x,y)= 2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{2x-1}(t)\cos^{2y-1}(t)dt$$

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt[n]{\sin(t)}dt= 0.5 B\left(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} + 1\right)}=\frac{n\sqrt{\pi}\  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)}$$

$$L =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }  n \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{n\sqrt{\pi}\  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)} \right)$$

This limit is very hard to deal with, I tried to use Gauss product of the gamma function to try to simplify this mess but it didn't work.

---

I noticed that if we define $f(x)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\sin^x (t)}dt$ assuming $f'(0) $ exist at $0$

$$-f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{1-\sin^h (t)}dt }{h}= L$$

$$ \dfrac{d}{d x}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\sin^x (t)}dt=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}   {\sin^x (t)}dt \ \ \  $$
Assuming we can interchange the derivative and the integral.

$$L = -\lim_{x \to 0}x \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\sin^{x-1} (t)}dt $$

Assuming all of these steps are true and could be justified $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0}x \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\sin^{x-1} (t)}dt $ is a hard limit and using the beta function will create the same mess as the first approach.

Comment: Note that $$-f'(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\sin t\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2.$$ I am not sure why you are suddenly considering $\lim_{x\to 0} x\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{x-1}t\,\mathrm{d}t$ which is not related to $f'(x)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I completely forgot about that definition of $\ln(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
n \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1 - \sqrt[n]{\sin t}) \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1 - (\sin t)^{1/n}}{1/n} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{1} (\sin t)^{s/n}(-\log \sin t) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Since the integrand is non-negative and increasing in $n$, we can invoke the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma) to conclude that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1 - \sqrt[n]{\sin t}) \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin t)^{s/n}(-\log \sin t) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{1} (-\log \sin t) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (-\log \sin t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \log 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ and
\begin{equation}
J_\epsilon = \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\epsilon\ln\sin t}d t
\end{equation}
Use Taylor-Lagrange formula $e^u = 1 + u + \frac{u^2}{2}e^{\theta u}$ with $\theta\in[0, 1]$, then
\begin{equation}
|J_\epsilon - \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin(t) d t|\le \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^2(\sin(t)) d t
\end{equation}
this shows that the limit is $-\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin(t) d t$

Comment: What is Taylor-Lagrange formula?

Comment: A famous integral evaluated e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/220759).

Comment: It is just the Taylor formula with the Lagrange's remainder (1797)

Comment: @Gribouillis do you have reference for that ?

Comment: References are easy to find, for example Wolfram https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html See also this blog https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/

Answer (score 2):

*To obtain more than the limit itself.*

As you properly wrote
$$A=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt[n]{\sin(t)}\,dt=n \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2 n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2 n}\right)}$$
Take logarithms and Taylor expand
$$\log(A)=\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\frac{\log (2)}{n}+\frac{\pi
   ^2}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Exponentiate and Taylor again
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\pi  \log (2)}{2 n}+\frac{\pi 
   \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\log ^2(2)\right)}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

So,
$$n \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\Big(1- \sqrt[n]{\sin(t)}\Big)\,dt=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log (2)-\frac{\pi  \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{12}+\log^2(2)\right)}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$